# How to check if an assembly contains unit tests without loading it?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-assembly

I'm currently using the following method to check for test assemblies:

```
private bool IsTestAssembly(string path)
{
    var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(path);
    foreach (var type in assembly.GetTypes())
    {
        var a = type.GetCustomAttributes(true).Select(x => x.ToString());
        if (a.Contains("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestClassAttribute"))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

But I would like to check this without loading the assembly in memory because I need to be able to delete it afterwards in case the verification fails.

I was hoping I could simply unload the assembly, but I soon discovered that, according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173101%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> There is no way to unload an individual assembly without unloading all of the application domains that contain it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Load it in a new appdomain?

Comment: Isn't this what Assembly.ReflectionOnlloadFrom should be used for?

Comment: I would recommend you adopt the convention of naming the assemblies `.Test` or `.Tests`. This is how VS/TFS does it with regards to running tests for builds as well.

Comment: @Anders Forsgren: I don't think **ReflectionOnlloadFrom** will work. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.reflectiononlyloadfrom.aspx) states that: *"The reflection-only context is no different from other contexts. Assemblies that are loaded into the context can be unloaded only by unloading the application domain."*

Comment: Aha. Separate domain is the way to go then unless it can be done by convention such as naming.

Comment: @TheGreatCO: Yeeah, I think a separate AppDomain will be the way to go. I'm also evaluating Robert Harvey's answer, but his solution seems like an overkill to my simple problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I worked out a short solution as suggested by [TheGreatCO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1120092/pete-garafano), i.e. to load the assembly in a new `AppDomain`:

1) Usage:

```
// assemblies are unloaded on disposal
using (var analyser = new AssemblyAnalyser())
{
    var path = "my.unit.tests.dll";
    var b = analyser.IsTestAssembly(path);
    Assert.IsTrue(b);
}
```

2) Implementation:

```
public class AssemblyAnalyser : MarshalByRefObject, IDisposable
{
    public AssemblyAnalyser()
    {
        var evidence = new Evidence(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence);
        var appSetup = new AppDomainSetup()
        {
            ApplicationBase = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
        };
        appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(otherDomainFriendlyName, evidence, appSetup); 
    }

    public bool IsTestAssembly(string assemblyPath)
    {
        if (AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName != otherDomainFriendlyName)
        {
            var analyser = appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName, GetType().FullName);
            return ((AssemblyAnalyser)analyser).IsTestAssembly(assemblyPath);
        }
        else
        {
            var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath);
            return ContainsTestClasses(assembly);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName != otherDomainFriendlyName)
        {
            AppDomain.Unload(appDomain);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }

    ~AssemblyAnalyser()
    {
        Dispose();
    }

    private bool ContainsTestClasses(Assembly assembly)
    {
        foreach (var type in assembly.GetTypes())
        {
            var attr = type.GetCustomAttributes(true).Select(x => x.ToString());
            if (attr.Contains("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestClassAttribute"))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private const string otherDomainFriendlyName = "AssemblyAnalyser";

    private AppDomain appDomain;
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, however in my case the cost of creating a new `AppDomain` was to high. It was cheaper for me to load all assemblies anyway, and after that filter them, and ignore types from assemblies identified by verifying if referenced assemblies contains a reference to NUnit.

Answer (score 2):

Inspect the assemblies using [Mono.Cecil](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil).  Cecil does not need to load the assembly to inspect it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I worked out a shorter solution that fits my needs. **Mono.Cecil** seems great, but I think it'd be an overkill to use it to address my specific problem.